# How do I understand which page of my theme is being loaded?

Tags: themes

Inside my theme there are tons of pages: 
page-nosidebar.php
pages.php
content.php

How can I track which is actually loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for your understanding, then install the [Query Monitor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), which gives you a lot of information about what's going on under the hood